# How to get the properties of entity class in Entity Framework Code First at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have DB context and entity class defined as follows:

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DBContext()
        : base("name=DbConnectionString")
    { }

    public virtual DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public long FooID { get; set; }
    public string Bar1 { get; set; }
    public string Bar2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get the properties of class Foo at runtime. I've tried reflection :

```
DBContext db = new DBContext(dbConnString);
db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
List<PropertyInfo> properties = db.Foos.GetType().GetProperties();
```

This code doesn't compile. How do I get the properties of class Foo? Thanks!

Comment: which compile error do you get?

Comment: the code you posted here should not have any error, there must be some other code. Also it should be `typeof(Foo)` instead of `db.Foos.GetType()`. Ah I guess the exception is `NullReferenceException`? `Foos` is not initialized inside the constructor of your context. However it does not matter when using `typeof(Foo)`

Comment: db.Foos.GetType() this returns either DbSet<Foo> or (more likely) null, since you did not specify the assembly. As suggested, use typeof() instead of GetType().

Comment: Thanks everyone. Using typeof(Foo) does the trick. A follow-up question, what BindingFlags should I use to get all properties except the key? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. The solution is as follows:

```
DBContext db = new DBContext(dbConnString);
db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Foos).GetProperties();
foreach (var prop in properties)
{
    process(prop.Name);
}
```